# Google Photos API - why are some querys POST and some GET?

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

From the documentation at the Google Photo API [Docs](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/list)
it states that to get mediaItems in general that is done using a GET request:
"GET https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems"

But for getting mediaItems from a specific album is done using a POST request (scroll down on the link) : 
"POST https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search"

It works fine, I am just wondering why getting mediaItems from a specific album is a POST request and not a GET request? I do not see the need for a POST since the request should not change the state on the server (as far as I can seee) 
(and getting mediaItems in general is indeed a GET request).

Comment: We have no special insight into what was going through the minds of Google's API designers when they designed that API. Voting off-topic as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Yeah, but it could be that some of the Google developers actually look at stackoverflow since they mention the stackoverflow tag for the Google Photos specificially in the documentation for the API. So there is always the hope one of them would answer. Furthermore, since the API is in Beta I think this is legimate question to highlight a "strange" difference in the API calls.